# Marginal Effect for Poisson Model

Tags: causality, poisson-regression, matching, treatment-effect, marginal-effect

I am using package **marginaleffects** for calculating the AME of an exposure variable on a count dependent variable. I am hence using Poisson (and Negative Binomial as robustness). The dependent variable in this case maps the number of days that pass from the request for a license to the approval, while the exposure is "prior_conviction", measuring whether the person asking for the license was previously convicted for a felony.

If I fit the model via glm using a matched dataset, I use:

```
model_matched <- glm(days_to_license ~
                      prior_conviction + age + 
                      sex+
                      prio_experience+
                      decade+
                      premises_type,
                    family=poisson, data = matched_dataset, weights=weights)
```

Let's assume these are all the confounders I need to control for. Then, to obtain the IRR, I use:

```
summ(model_matched, exp = TRUE, robust=TRUE, digits=3)
```

After this, I get that the coefficient is 1.059, meaning that having a prior conviction leads to an increase by 5.9% in the number of days needed to get the license.

I would also like to compute the AME, and hence I use:

```
ame_matched<-comparisons(model_matched, variables = "prior_conviction",
                           newdata = subset(matched_dataset, prior_conviction == 1)) |>summary()
```

Once I compute this; I get that the effect is 1.986. Is it correct then to conclude that for those having prior convictions, it takes on average 1.99 more days to receive the license, compared to those who do not have a prior conviction?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Negative binomial is not more robust than Poisson, so don't use it. You should be using a quasi-Poisson regression, which can be requested using `family = quasipoisson`. Negative binomial requires the model for the mean and (over-dispersed) variance to be correct; quasi-Poisson is consistent if just the mean function is correct specified. You need to use a robust standard error with quasi-Poisson (but you should be using that anyway).

If your matched sample size is large, you should include interactions between the treatment and covariates. This is also required if you don't achieve good balance after matching (though if that is the case, you should respecify the match).

If you are trying to estimate the marginal IRR, you can use essentially the same code as you would the the ATT. This code is below:

```r
#ATT
avg_comparisons(model_matched, variables = "prior_conviction",
                newdata = subset(matched_dataset, prior_conviction == 1),
                vcov = ~subclass)

#ATT IRR
avg_comparisons(model_matched, variables = "prior_conviction",
                newdata = subset(matched_dataset, prior_conviction == 1),
                vcov = ~subclass,
                comparison = "lnratioavg",
                transform = exp)
```

You need to make sure you adjust the standard errors for pair membership if you performed pair or full matching.

Comment: Hi Noah. Thanks for your continuous support with marginaleffects. Your work is tremendously important. 

Some questions: 1) the code I used for the AME in my post is hence not correct? 2) why do I need to include interactions between the exposure and the covariates? I used marginaleffects for Logit before and never used it. 3) I performed exact matching with substitution, do I need to adjust the standard errors as well? If so, how would you do it? Ps: agree on the NB comment, I have to do it nonetheless due to advisor’s request.